# What is the equation of a half sine wave?

Tags: trigonometry

Basically, I am trying to generate a half sine wave using excel. The waveform that I am looking for is a wave which has a positive component from $0$ to $\pi$ and a zero component from $\pi$ to $2\pi$. Image attached for reference (red graph). I'm looking for the equation of said graph. [Graph of half-rectified sine wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw0Yx.png)

Comment: Can you define it piecewise? $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(x) & \text{if } x\in [2k\pi, 3k\pi] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: `MAX(x,0)` will clamp any value to nonnegative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(x) + \left| \sin{x} \right| \right)
$$

Comment: The 1/2 was unnecessary for the shape that i wanted but thanks for the reply! Truly appreciated!